# Soft Returns in Officer

Tags: r, officer

How can one do "soft" returns for `docx` files from officer? To do it manually, I'd press `SHIFT + ENTER` and alter the ruler tabs to offset subsequent lines. But the heading will show as one line in the table of contents.

I have not been able to reproduce this programmatically.

No methods found in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Soft return is not a feature of `officer`. If you want a new line of text, you will have to add a new paragraph.

```
library(magrittr)

doc <- read_docx() %>%
  body_add_par("A paragraph", style = "Normal") %>%
  body_add_par("A new paragraph is starting on a new line", style = "Normal")
```

Answer (score -4):

If you're just looking to enter a return into the same paragraph, you can use \n:

```
library(officer)

my_doc <- read_docx() $>$
  body_add_par("This is on the first line.\nThis is on the next line")
```